# All numbers that are NOT in an array under 1000

Tags: php

I've got this programming problem.

I have number for example 1000.

Now I have a number in an array, like 999.

Now I need to display all numbers that are NOT in the array but are 1 to 1000;

The next requirement is essential:
It has to be displayed in a way that it's easy to oversee.

So I was thinking, lets show:

```
100
200
300
400
500
600
700
800
900
910
920
930
940
950
960
970
980
990
991
992
993
994
995
996
997
998
1000
```

What is the best way to start programming this?

Comment: I don't get it. Is your array `array(999)`? What does "all numbers that are NOT in the array but are 1 to 1000" mean?

Comment: This is simple set math (slightly more complex if you actually don't want to have a set with 1000 elements in it, but that's small enough that you probably don't care).  Is this homework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$in_array = array (999);
$flipped = array_flip($in_array);
for ($i = 1; $i < 1000; $i++)
{
    if (!isset($flipped[$i]))
    {
         $out_array[] = $i;
    }
}
echo implode(" ", $out_array);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$myArray = array(999);
$notInArray = array_diff(range(1,1000),$myArray);
echo implode("\n", $notInArray);
```